# How to animate a div opening to the size of its content

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I would like to animate the opening of a div to adjust to the size of its content. The content comes from a separate search that I call with a .load so it could be as small as a single line (no result) or could include multiple results that are hundreds of pixels long. I have scanned many postings on this and tried a variety of things but so far haven't gotten any results.

My latest idea is to start the animation a small amount so that it appears to be opening and then set the height to auto so it will jump to the final size. The result is that the first animation occurs but the height stays where it set it. The following is taken from my document ready function:

```
$( "##TwoSearch" ).click(function() {
    $("##div1").animate({ height:0 }, 500).empty(); <!--- close div 1 --->
    $("##div2").animate({ height:200 }, 500);
    SW=document.getElementById("SearchWords").value;
    $("##div2").load("TwoSearchExercise.cfm?SW=" + encodeURI(SW), function () {
        $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT(); 
        $("##div2").css('height','auto');
        });
    });
```

Is there a clean way to do this? I've tried to pull the height from inside the div but it doesn't seem to do anything.

PS: This is a ColdFusion app so please ignore the ## notation.

Comment: $(".element").slideDown(); Why are you using double ## as selectors, this is confusing...

Comment: Also, you have an html comment in a javascript file, this is an error (<!-- HTML COMMENT -->). This is a bit of a mess, let me set up a fiddle for oyu

Comment: if the div is taking the correct size after you insert the dynamic content, then a css transition might do the trick ? Sorry if I'm not quite on track, animations aren't my strong side.

Comment: @astian you can't transition to height: auto; in css. There's a workaround with min-height but it's not perfect. I'd go with jQuery on this one.

Comment: Like I said, this is a ColdFusion app so please ignore the CF notations. The ## and the CF comment have no relevance on the issue (the CF server removes them before they hit the browser).

Comment: I have tried the  slidedown and it didn't result in any change. The page just jumps to the full size as if jQuery isn't involved.

Comment: Have you seen my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has a couple of errors:
first: don't use double ## as a selector, this is confusing.
second: You have an html comment in your javascript, this will lead to a javascript error.
Comments in html files are like this: `<!--comment-->` while in javascript files you can use `//comment` for single line comments of `/* comment */` for multiline comments.

I had to comment out your ajax part as I don't have a webserver running around here, I simulated it with a timeout of 1 second. Here's the corrected code:

```js
$( "#TwoSearch" ).click(function() {
    $("#div2").slideUp("fast");
    $("#div1").animate({ height:0 }, 500).empty();
    $("#div2").animate({ height:200 }, 500).empty();
    SW=document.getElementById("SearchWords").value;
    /*$("#div2").load("TwoSearchExercise.cfm?SW=" + encodeURI(SW), function () {
        $('.js-lazyYT').lazyYT(); 
        $("#div2").css('height','auto');
        });*/
        //REMOVE FROM HERE
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        var string = "Lorem upsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adiscip. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. "
        var loops = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
        var finalstring = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < loops; i++) {
            finalstring+=string;
        }
        $("#div2").text(finalstring);
        $("#div2").slideDown("slow");
        //TO HERE, IT'S JUST CREATING RANDOM TEXT TO DEMONSTRATE THE FIDDLE, REPLACE WITH YOUR AJAX CODE
    }, 1000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="TwoSearch">TwoSearch</button>
<input type="text" id="SearchWords" >
<div id="div1">
    
</div>

<div id="div2">
    
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the css('height','auto'); to a slidedown("slow") but it didn't appear to  do anything. The div just went to its full size immediately.